Is axiom of pairing consequence of axiom of specification+axiom of unions+axiom of powers?
I am reading "Naive set theory" by Paul R. Halmos and I have the next question:
Is the axiom of pairing consequence of axioms of specification,union and power?
Let $A$ and $B$ two given sets, by the axiom of unions we have the set $A \cup B$.
Now, by the axiom of powers we have the set $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$. Note that $A,B \subseteq A \cup B$ so $A,B \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.
Finally, we applicate the axiom of specification to the set $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ with the next condition:
$\{X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) | X=A$ or $X=B\}$
and we obtein the set $\{A,B\}$, and that is the same set that we obtein applying axiom of pairing to the sets $A$ and $B$.
What is wrong in my proof?

The axiom of union doesn't give you the existence of $A \cup B$ because it only applies to families of sets: if $\mathcal{A}$ is a family of sets, then its union $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ exists. In order to express $A \cup B$ as such a union you would have to take $\mathcal{A} = \{ A, B \}$, but this is the set the existence of which you are trying to prove. So this can't work.
I don't think you can prove the axiom of pairing using just the three mentioned axioms (although I don't have a model that exemplifies it). But you can do it using the empty set axiom, the power set axiom and the axiom of replacement:

take the empty set $\varnothing$,
use the power set axiom to construct $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\varnothing)) = \{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \} \}$,
define the formula $\varphi(x, y)$ (with parameters $A, B$) so that $\varphi( \varnothing, A )$ and $\varphi( \{ \varnothing \}, B )$ is true and everything else is false,
use the axiom of replacement to the set $\{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \} \}$ and the formula $\varphi$, obtaining $\{ A, B \}$.


Thank you very much for your response.

Okay, I have a model showing that the three axioms are insufficient. Let $M = U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint copies of the family of hereditarily finite sets $V_{\omega}$ in $\text{ZFC}$. Then $M$ satisfies the axioms, but the set ${ \varnothing_U, \varnothing_V }$, consisting of the respective copies of the empty set, does not exist in $M$.

What is a model? What are hereditarily finite sets?
